# Selected items disappear during search in v-select selections

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have implemented something similar to this code pen in one of my projects.

https://codepen.io/sudheer-ranga/pen/bGVbjbx

There is one issue that am facing, the selected items disappear for invalid search.
So, I found out that the items prop is mutating. Furthermore, I added cache-items prop, that did keep the selected items intact. But now the search would not filter the items.

Next, I added a computed property to get the updated items after search and update it in the items.

```
computed: {
 finalOptions() {
    return this.fruitsCopy;
 }
}
```

https://codepen.io/nyfer/pen/VwGdKvy

But that doesn't work too.
So, I would like to know how I can go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general recommendation is to not implement your own search, but instead use Vuetify's [`v-autocomplete`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/), which is a select with builtin search capability:

```html
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="selectedFruits"
  :items="fruits"
  attach label="Favorite Fruits"
  multiple
></v-autocomplete>
```

If you insist on having the input on top of the item list, you can still use the same slot you used before and make the initial input invisible:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: '',
      selectedFruits: [],
      fruits: [
        "Apples",
        "Apricots",
        "Avocado",
        "Bananas",
        "Blueberries",
        "Blackberries",
        "Boysenberries",
        "Bread fruit",
        "Cantaloupes (cantalope)",
        "Cherries",
        "Cranberries",
        "Cucumbers",
        "Currants",
        "Dates",
        "Eggplant",
        "Figs",
        "Grapes",
        "Grapefruit",
        "Guava",
        "Honeydew melons",
        "Huckleberries",
        "Kiwis",
        "Kumquat",
        "Lemons",
        "Limes",
        "Mangos",
        "Mulberries",
        "Muskmelon",
        "Nectarines",
        "Olives",
        "Oranges",
        "Papaya",
        "Peaches",
        "Pears",
        "Persimmon",
        "Pineapple",
        "Plums",
        "Pomegranate",
        "Raspberries",
        "Rose Apple",
        "Starfruit",
        "Strawberries",
        "Tangerines",
        "Tomatoes",
        "Watermelons",
        "Zucchini"
      ],
    };
  },
})
```

```css
.v-select__selections input{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
<div class="pa-4">
    <v-autocomplete v-model="selectedFruits" :items="fruits" attach label="Favorite Fruits" :search-input.sync="searchTerm" multiple>
    <template v-slot:prepend-item>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-text-field v-model="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" @input="searchFruits"></v-text-field>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
        </template>
    
    </v-autocomplete>
</div>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, if I could alter the position of the search. then would be happy to use that. I couldn't find any v-slot option for search to customize it.

Comment: Oh, you can use the same slot as before. Have a loot at the updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

You need to push back selected items to search,
see here [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/yeejiawei/pen/xxazRme?editors=1010)

```js
// Option 1 forEach
this.selectedFruits.forEach((selectedFruit) => {
    this.fruits.push(selectedFruit);
});
      
// Options 2 spread syntax
this.fruits = [
    ...this.selectedFruits,
    ...this.fruits,
];
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted selected items to visible in the label, but not when filtering the items during search.